# Der Unterschied zwischen "von Beruf" und "arbeite als"

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Hier verstehe ich nicht:

> Ich bin 25 Jahre alt und von Beruf Lehrerin. Ich arbeite als Programmiererin.

Was bedeutet das hier?  Sie war Lehrerin und jetzt ist Programmiererin?  Oder studierte sie vorher Lehramt aber nun gibt sie Lehramt auf und arbeitet für IT?

[image: filled from example]

Answer (score 5):

*Arbeiten als* beschreibt, welcher Tätigkeit eine Person nachgeht. *Von Beruf* erklärt, welche Ausbildung eine Person abgeschlossen hat.

Hier sind verschiedene Kombinationen denkbar:

1. Eine Person hat eine bestimmte Ausbildung und übt nun eine bestimmte Tätigkeit aus, für die diese Ausbildung eine Voraussetzung ist:

> Von Beruf bin ich Bäcker und zur Zeit arbeite ich als Techniker in einer Brotfabrik.

2. Eine Person hat eine bestimmte Ausbildung, über aber eine damit nicht zusammenhängende, in der Regel ungelernte Tätigkeit oder eine Tätigkeit als Quereinsteiger aus:

> Von Beruf bin ich Bäcker, arbeite zur Zeit aber als Paketbote.

*Von Beruf* kann auch für Erwerbstätigkeiten verwendet werden, für die es keine Ausbildung gibt, dann ist es gleichbedeutend mit *arbeiten als*:

3. Von Beruf bin ich YouTuber.

*Von Beruf* kann nicht für Ausbildungen verwendet werden, aus denen keine klare Berufstätigkeit hervorgeht, wie z.B. Studiengänge:

4. <strike>Von Beruf bin ich Germanist.</strike> ("Germanist" ist kein Beruf, "Professor für neuere deutsche Sprache" schon.)

Answer (score 4):

Ein Beruf ist eine Arbeit, der man dauerhaft nachgeht, meist hat man dazu eine entsprechende Ausbildung in irgendeiner Form.

Wenn jemand eine Ausbildung als Lehrerin genossen hat und als Lehrerin arbeitet, dann ist Lehrerin der Beruf dieser Person.

Wenn sie dagegen dauerhaft, nicht nur temporär, als Programmiererin arbeitet, dann wird Programmiererin ihr Beruf, und ihr Beruf ist dann nicht mehr Lehrerin. Man sagt auch: Sie wechselt den Beruf. Damit ist ein dauerhafter Wechsel gemeint.

Wenn sie nur kurzfristig als Programmiererin arbeitet, zum Beispiel um Arbeitslosigkeit zu vermeiden, sich aber eigentlich als Lehrerin sieht und den Beruf der Lehrerin auch in Zukunft wieder *ausüben* möchte, kann sie sagen, dass sie als Programmiererin arbeitet, aber ihr Beruf (oder, wie man dann oft sagt, ihr *eigentlicher Beruf*) Lehrerin ist.

Answer (score 2):

Meines Erachtens kann *von Beruf ... sein* zwei Dinge bedeuten:

1. man hat eine bestimmte Erwerbstätigkeit durch eine formale/allgemein anerkannte Ausbildung erlernt,

aber auch:

2. man übt eine Erwerbstätigkeit über eine längere Zeit als Hauptbeschäftigung (*hauptberuflich*) aus und erwirbt dadurch mit einer Ausbildung vergleichbare praktische Kenntnisse.

Zu (1): Hier schwingt der Begriff *Berufung* mit, also die spirituelle Vorstellung, dass jedem Menschen eine Tätigkeit vorherbestimmt ist, die er erlernen und meistern sollte. Im deutschsprachigen Raum geschieht das traditionell im Rahmen einer formalen, ein- bis dreijährigen dualen Ausbildung an einer Berufsschule und in einem Betrieb, die z.B. mit einem Gesellenbrief (bei Handwerksberufen) oder einer Prüfung vor der Industrie- und Handelskammer abgeschlossen wird. Die abschließende Liste von Berufen, die an Berufsschulen erlernt werden kann, bezeichnet man als **Ausbildungsberufe**. *Von Beruf ... sein* kann bedeuten, welchen *Ausbildungsberuf* man erlernt hat. Manche Berufe werden auch durch Studiengänge erlernt, z.B. der des Maschinenbauingenieurs oder des Arztes. Auch hier kann man ohne Weiteres von Beruf sprechen.

Zu (2): Im standardmäßigen Sprachgebrauch kann jedoch meines Erachtens auch eine langfristig schwerpunktmäßig ausgeübte, nicht formalisierte Tätigkeit zum Beruf werden, sofern Zeit und Routine zu einer Verinnerlichung der Abläufe führten, die mit einer Ausbildung vergleichbar wäre, die für die jeweilige Tätigkeit nicht existiert. Beispiel: ein langjähriger Taxifahrer, der seine Stadt kennt und den Umgang mit verschiedenen Arten von Fahrgästen beherrscht, könnte sich durchaus als *Taxifahrer von Beruf* bezeichnen, gerade weil es hierzu keine formale Ausbildung gibt.

---

Für die Frage bedeutet das: Möglichkeit (2) scheidet aus, da man Lehrerin (zumindest an einer staatlichen Schule) nur durch ein entsprechendes Studium werden kann. Somit ist es eindeutig, dass die Sprecherin meint, dass sie Lehramt studiert hat. Den Beruf der Programmiererin hingegen hat sie offenbar nicht erlernt, arbeitet aber als solche. (Diese Aussage schließt gleichzeitig aus, dass sie in ihrem Beruf als Lehrerin arbeitet.)

Answer (score 1):

Wie schon in der Frage vermutet, verweist "von Beruf" auf die Ausbildung und "arbeite als" auf die derzeitige Tätigkeit. Für die Arbeit als Programmiererin ist aber auch eine Ausbildung notwendig. Ausbildung ist hier im weiteren Sinn gemeint und nicht unbedingt als Lehre/Ausbildungsberuf.

Die Implikation ist normalerweise, dass man einen Beruf gelernt hat, den man ausüben wollte, und dann auf eine andere Tätigkeit gewechselt hat, weil dort die wirtschaftlichen Aussichten besser sind. Oder auch, weil der erste Beruf doch nicht so war, wie man es sich vorgestellt hatte.

PS:
Bezüglich der Frage wegen Ausbildung, damit kann im engeren Sinne gemeint sein, was ein Auszubildender/Lehrling lernt, traditionell von einem Meister, inzwischen mit Berufsschule, zum Teil auch Branchen, die keine Meistertitel führen. Die Details dazu gehen aber zu weit im Rahmen dieser Frage.
Oben aber jede Art von Ausbildung gemeint, also auch Studium oder selbst lernen.

Und um als Programmiererin zu arbeiten, ist sicherlich eine Ausbildung notwendig, wenn auch nicht unbedingt eine formale Ausbildung oder ein Abschluss.

Comment: Wieso ist für die Arbeit als Programmierer eine Ausbildung erforderlich? Und was ist mit *Ausbildung im weiteren Sinne gemeint*?

Comment: @DavidVogt 10 Minuten auf SX oder 2 Minuten mit fremden Quelltext und du weißt warum ;) . Aber ja, ist missverständlich formuliert ^^

Comment: Wir haben es beim Fragesteller mit einem Sprachlerner zu tun. In diesem Fall finde ich es nicht angemessen, so zu tun, als ob man sich als ausgebildeter Programmierer bezeichnen könnte, wenn man es sich selber beigebracht hat. In einem Vorstellungsgespräch wäre das ein *faux pas*. Daher -1.

Comment: @DavidVogt Wo habe ich behautet, dass vorgeben könne, man hätte einen Abschuss, den man nicht hat? Was für einen Zusammenhang hat die Frage oder die Antwort mit einem Vorstellungsgespräch? Und das, nachdem im ersten Kommentar noch angezweifelt wurde, dass eine Ausbildung überhaupt erforderlich wäre. Es gab schon Leute, die programmieren konnten, lange bevor eine formelle Ausbildung dazu geschaffen wurde.

Comment: Verstehe ich da etwas falsch? Du hast doch geschrieben, dass Selbststudium als Ausbildung "im weiteren Sinn" bezeichnet werden kann. Und das finde ich extrem irreführend und nicht hilfreich für den Fragesteller. Was der Fragesteller wissen wollte, steht im ersten Satz der Antwort. Inwiefern der Rest der Antwort dem Fragesteller hilft, sehe ich nicht.

Comment: @DavidVogt Programmieren will gelernt sein, wie jede andere Tätigkeit auch. Wenn sie jetzt als Programmiererin arbeitet, hat sie es irgendwann gelernt, sonst könnte sie es jetzt nicht. Es wäre daher falsch zu sagen, Lehrerin hat sie gelernt, Programmiererin hat sie nicht gelernt. Lernen kann man in der Schule, an der Uni, in der Lehre, VHS usw., oder auch eigenständig. Vielleicht hat sie eine Umschulung gemacht, vielleicht hat sie immer mehr Aufgaben in der Richtung bekommen, bis sie ganz darauf gewechselt ist. In der Frage geht es um das Ausfüllen eines Lückentextes, nicht um eine Bewerbung.